# Add Product without category o subcategory in Magento 2 with direct link

Tags: url, magento2, product

Good morning, I hope you can help me, how can I create a product in Magento 2 that is enabled but does not appear in any category?
Let me explain, the product must be reachable only via link and not visible on the category/subcategory pages.

Answer (score 0):

When you create the new product, don't add it to any categories (This is optional and so you can create it without one). You'll also want to ensure that you set "Visibility" to "Catalog" that way it won't show up in search. Once created, this product will be available at the "URL key" value (+ .HTML) specified in the Search Engine Optimization area of the product configuration.